# NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python

i'm getting

```
NameError: global name 'Ontologia' is not defined
```

The class Ontologia is defined on ontologia.py and I also used

```
import ontologia
```

This is the line that i'm getting the problem

```
onto = Ontologia()
```

The full code of ontologia.py is here:

```
class Ontologia(object):

def __init__(self, name, key, left=None, right=None):
    self.name = name
    self.key = key
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

Comment: Try either (but not both) `from ontologia import Ontologia`, or `onto = ontologia.Ontologia()`.

Comment: Please put your answer in an answer, so OP can accept it, I can vote on it, and the world can know this question was answered.

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Is there a way for me to import the whole module?

Answer (score 3):

Python's [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) statement works a bit different from for example Java's `import` statement.

It's possible to import every public name from a module.  If you're interested, the [documentation of the `import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) defines exactly what's a "public name".  For example:

```
from ontologia import *
onto = Ontologia()  # name 'Ontologia' is defined now
```

In general it isn't recommended to use this form because it's not clear which name was defined by which `import` statement.  Python programmers like to be explicit.

Better is:

```
from ontologia import Ontologia
onto = Ontologia()  # name 'Ontologia' is defined now
```

Or:

```
import ontologia
onto = ontologia.Ontologia()
```